# How to declare Heap Space in docker file for the docker container containing java app

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am using jar file in docker image while I have to increase my JVM memory to 1gb how can I do that through a docker file.

Current Docker file below attached.

```
FROM anapsix/alpine-java

MAINTAINER XXXXX


ENV JAVA_OPTS="-xmx1024m -xms1024m"

COPY file-send-jar-0.0.0.jar /home/file-send-jar-0.0.0.jar

CMD ["java","-jar","/home/file-send-jar-0.0.0.jar"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to give java the XMX settings in `CMD`

Example:

`CMD["java","-Xmx1024m", "-Xms1024m","-jar","/home/file-send-jar-0.0.0.jar"]`

Do note that `CMD` doesn't do variable substitution. See the [Docker file reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd).

> Note: Unlike the shell form, the exec form does not invoke a command
>   shell. This means that normal shell processing does not happen. For
>   example, CMD [ "echo", "$HOME" ] will not do variable substitution on
>   $HOME. If you want shell processing then either use the shell form or
>   execute a shell directly, for example: CMD [ "sh", "-c", "echo $HOME"
>   ]. When using the exec form and executing a shell directly, as in the
>   case for the shell form, it is the shell that is doing the environment
>   variable expansion, not docker.

Comment: didnt get you i am not sure what you mean by ECHO to show java memory

Comment: `CMD [ "java", "-Xmx1024m", "-Xms1024m", "-jar", "/home/file-send-jar-0.0.0.jar" ]`